# Authlogic: verifying login/password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Without creating a session, I want to check the validity of a login/pw. How do I do this with authlogic?

I've been digging through authlogic's code, but I figure it would be much faster for someone familiar with the code base to just tell me the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask you why don't you want to create a user session? Because authlogic is based on the concept of sessions and it seems kind of pointless to use it without them

Comment: This is for a mobile phone login where I simply want to return user information if the login/password is supplied correctly.

Comment: I am using sessions for interactions with the website outside of the mobile app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On any `User` object:

```
user.valid_password?("password") #=> true
```